# Why does restoring iPad not restore e-mail? Best way to fix?

Tags: ipad, mail.app, restore

iPad Air 2 was stolen.

Six days later, iPad Pro arrived as replacement.

iTunes restore from local backup.  Makes me pick a new security code instead of restoring that.

Also, I open mail and NONE of the accounts I had before are there, but there are three (only) messages in a generic inbox from two of those accounts.  And they are three weeks old; lots of messages came in since.

Why is this, and is there an easy fix?

Comment: Sigh.  I reloaded the profiles of the IMAP accounts, and the folders fixed themselves.  Then the Exchange account, which had stopped working on the old iPad, somehow fixed itself!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you made a **non**-encrypted Backup on iTunes, since you had to make a new code.

The Apple KB article [About backups for iOS devices](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204136) states:

> From your Mac or PC, you can make a backup of your device in iTunes. Syncing your device with your computer isn't the same as making a backup. An iTunes backup includes nearly all of your device's data and settings. An iTunes backup **doesn't** include:
>
> - Content from the iTunes and App Stores, or PDFs downloaded directly to iBooks (You can back up this content using Transfer Purchases in iTunes.)
> - Content synced from iTunes, like imported MP3s or CDs, videos, books, and photos
> - Photos already stored in the cloud, like My Photo Stream, and iCloud Photo Library
> - Touch ID settings
> - Apple Pay information and settings
> - Activity, Health, and **Keychain** data (To back up this content, you'll **need to use Encrypted Backup** in iTunes.)

I marked the points you are probably concerned about (your personal executive summary) :)
I am sorry to say you have to add them again from my perspective.

Comment: I believe I clearly indicated that the "point I was concerned about" is e-mail.  I don't see that marked.  I'm not quite as concerned about the unlock code, though I would expect that to be part of "data and SETTINGS"  I guess you could consider it Keychain data, but since I was using the iCloud Keychain, it should have re-synced that.  And how it managed to get one IMAP message and two Exchange messages without getting the accounts they come from is still a mystery.

Comment: Actually, if it failed to get the passwords from ICLoud keychain, then it should have had the accounts but error messages about not being able to connect.

Comment: It would definitely keychain data, as you do not want stored credentials on a backup lying around, that's why I marked the things I thought you **were** concerned about before you gave me more information. Don't expect too much. You know for sure how it is on here with over 700 reputation. Yes, after telling me you are using iCloud Keychain it should be working even without the encrypted backup, but it doesn't, so try to add them again in the settings. I think it is the easiest way as the iCloud keychain is behaving sometimes very weirdly when troubleshooting and then suddenly works again...

Comment: You could also try to relogin with the iCloud Keychain but from your description it looks like the Mail data is corrupt so trying to clean it by deleting and adding again in the settings is the best and easiest idea I have right now...

Comment: Well, I can add them by profiles which also should have been in the backup.  That's one per account and doesn't contain the password.  But I was hoping for a one-step thing for all the accounts.  And then after I install the profiles, I have to separately assign the drafts, sent, and inbox folders for every account.  The previous iPad (stolen) restored these things from the one before, so the failure this time is weird.  I guess this answer (when combined with the comments) is the best we're going to get.

Comment: @WGroleau Just to clarify, the "Keychain data" referred to in the Apple article is referring to the local Keychain stored on the device, which is where your email account would be. iCloud Keychain is never backed up even in an encrypted iTunes backup.

Comment: But once I login to it, it would provide the passwords for the mail servers when asked.  Only it doesn't get asked because iTunes didn't restore the accounts.